# Using docker socket in Kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I want to [prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) docker images, I wrote a small Docker image using `node-docker-api` and I was able to test it locally with success.
As I've deployed the `DaemonSet` to Kubernetes, the pod fails to access the Docker socket:

```
Error: connect EACCES /var/run/docker.sock
```

The `deployment.yaml` looks as following:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  labels:
    name: docker-image-cleanup
  name: docker-image-cleanup
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: docker-image-cleanup 
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: docker-sock
          hostPath:
            path: "/var/run/docker.sock"
            type: File
        - name: docker-directory
          hostPath:
            path: "/var/lib/docker"

      containers:
        - name: docker-image-cleanup
          image: image:tag
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          env:
            - name: PRUNE_INTERVAL_SECONDS
              value: "30"
            - name: PRUNE_DANGLING
              value: "true"
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
              name: docker-sock
              readOnly: false
            - mountPath: "/var/lib/docker"
              name: docker-directory
              readOnly: false
```

Running AKS v1.13.10 - if relevant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've added `runAsUser: 0` to the container properties:

```
containers:
  - name: docker-image-cleanup
    image: image:tag
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
      runAsUser: 0
```

Now it works

Answer (score 7):

There is no guarantee that your kubernetes cluster is actually using docker as container engine. As there are many alternatives like cri-o and kata containers your application/deployment should make no assumptions about the underlying container engine.

Kubernetes takes care about cleaning up unused container images automatically. See documentation on how to configure it, if you run the cluster yourself: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/

Aside from that it looks like you have a simple permission problem with the socket: Make sure your application in the cleanup container runs as root or has appropriate user to access the socket.

Comment: I've made sure Docker is used. Unfortunately due to some other issues, we have to prune the unused images much more intensively than the integrated garbage collector

Comment: Why do you have to manually remove images, what happens if you don't? I would fix the underlying issue and not aim for breaking the abstraction provided by kubernetes.

Comment: Company requirement. Thank you for the good intentions but I prefer to get an answer (if possible) for the issue I've introduced :)

Comment: What is the requirement exactly?

Comment: Not to leave unused images more than x minutes on nodes

Comment: Post edit: the question is actually how should I solve the simple permission issue